# How to make the inner stateful widget received the scroll event in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, gridview

I have a GridView inside a ListView, but the GridView is contained inside different Stateful widget. I noticed that the ScrollController I put on GridView is never called, but I need that so that I can detect whether the screen has reached bottom so I can load the next batch of data (infinite scrolling). How am I supposed to do that? I've tried to add `primary: true` to the GridView and `primary: false` to the ListView but it doesn't work.

```
class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget
-> final userId: String;
-> build () {
   -> ListView {
      -> children: [
         -> User avatar
         -> User name
         -> Action button
         -> TileGallery(userId: userId)

class TileGallery extends StatefulWidget
-> final _scrollController = Controller();
-> initState() {
   -> _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
-> build () {
   -> GridView {
      -> controller: _scrollController
-> _onScroll() {     // never called
```

Sorry for the weird code. The actual code has too many irrelevant code. The thing is, I used to use the TileGallery as a standalone screen Widget (e.g. has Scaffold on the build), and at that time, the `_onScroll()` function gets called. How can I solve this?

Comment: can you give me name of the file which contains this `Controller` class?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just `Controller`, create `ScrollController` instance.

Comment: Interesting. But at the moment I had to use a workaround which put all of those two widgets in one widget to simplify the rebuilding notification and data flow. Will try to use your solution on the next widget refactoring. Thanks.